# Working with large (over 2000x2000) images in Dlib, and they don't fit in my screen

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, dlib, keypoint

So after a few weeks, I finally managed to get Dlib installed, and immediately ran into another problem.

I downloaded and ran their face landmark dector: http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection.py.html and while the actual program works fine, when I try to run it on large images:

[image]

The images don't fit on my screen:

[image]

The code for the actual keymark extractor is here:

```
win = dlib.image_window()

for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.jpg")):
print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
    img = io.imread(f)

win.clear_overlay()
win.set_image(img)

# Ask the detector to find the bounding boxes of each face. The 1 in the
# second argument indicates that we should upsample the image 1 time. This
# will make everything bigger and allow us to detect more faces.
dets = detector(img, 1)
print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(dets)))
for k, d in enumerate(dets):
    print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {}".format(
        k, d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))
    # Get the landmarks/parts for the face in box d.
    shape = predictor(img, d)
    print("Part 0: {}, Part 1: {} ...".format(shape.part(0),
                                              shape.part(1)))
    # Draw the face landmarks on the screen.
    win.add_overlay(shape)
```

And despite combing through the Dlib documentation, there's no mention of window size in ghe `win.set_image()` or the `win.add_overlay()` functions.

How would I make the window smaller?

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the image you can drag it around.  Or hold ctrl and scroll the mouse wheel.  That lets you zoom just like it does in many other programs.

Comment: No, I know I can move it around. I want to change the actual image size.

Comment: So zoom out using the mouse wheel

Comment: I don't have a mouse wheel.

Answer (score 0):

There are some methods as in dlib:

```
pyramid_down();
resize_image();
```

you can resize image and then show to window.

Comment: And this works in python? I don't see it in the docs: http://dlib.net/python/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment now, you can resize the image as @Anuj Singh said in his answer and then pass it to window: http://dlib.net/python/index.html#dlib.resize_image

```py
img = dlib.resize_image(img, 600, 400)  # if you want to resize to 600x400 px
win.set_image(img)
```

I am not sure if this method was add in python3 or not since the original question asks about python2.7.